# one script to monitor incoming ssh connections to the server

Tags: linux, bash, monitoring, scripting

I want to make a script to monitor incoming ssh connections to the server.
Try ForceCommand in sshd_config but it will not let me in if I put it there
my script.

Match User * 
X11Forwarding no 
AllowTcpForwarding no 
ForceCommand ssh /usr/local/include/ssh.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
DP=/usr/local/include;
DT=$(w | grep pts | grep -v :0.0 > $DP/tmp.log);
FDATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d);
while read -r values
do
PTSU=$(echo $values |  awk '{print $2}');
IP=$(echo $values |  awk '{print $3}');
LTIME=$(echo $values |  awk '{print $4}');
USA=$(echo $values |  awk '{print $1}');


  PROC=$( cat /proc/net/arp | grep $IP );
  MAC=$(echo $PROC |  awk '{print $4}');

  echo "$USA $PTSU $IP $MAC $FDATE $LTIME" >>$DP/ssh.log;

done < $DP/tmp.log
rm $DP/tmp.log
```

Answer (score 3):

The ForceCommand must actually execute a command the user wants to run.  Perhaps a shell, perhaps a sftp daemon, rsync, or something else.  Your script is not doing anything other then trying to log the data you want.  So the ssh daemon starts your script, runs it, and when the script exist, the ssh session is terminated.  The `ForceCommand` comannd needs to either stay running to keep the session open or start something else that keeps the session open.

That script is a bit of a mess.  `ForceCommand` is run with the permissions of the user.  Hopefully your users don't have write access to `/usr/local/include` this directory should only be writable by root, it is not meant as a data folder.

You have a hard coded temp file name.  That is at the minimum could result in bugs if two users login at the same time.  Depending on the security of that directory you are storing stuff in, it could possibly be abused as a security bypass.  You don't seem to have any filtering to limit it to the currently active user.

Most of what you seem to be trying to log, the SSH daemon will already log, just bump up your verbosity (`LogLevel VERBOSE`) and extract the data will go to your syslog instead of trying to build some kind of hacky script for this purpose.

The only thing that wouldn't be part of standard verbose sshd log is the mac address you are getting from the arp command, which I really doubt it is all that useful in any case.  But, if you really think you need to know mac addresses maybe install something like [arpalert](http://www.arpalert.org/arpalert.html) to log mac to ip associations in your syslog.